# Can experiment distinguish the basis in which a singlet state is represented?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, hilbert-space

Let $\left(|\uparrow\rangle,|\downarrow\rangle\right)$ and $\left(|\nearrow\rangle,|\swarrow\rangle\right)$ be two bases of the $2$-dimensional Hilbert space $H$.

Can an experiment distinguish between $\frac 1{\sqrt 2} \left(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle - |\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\right)$ and $\frac 1{\sqrt 2} \left(|\nearrow\swarrow\rangle - |\swarrow\nearrow\rangle\right)$?

As vectors in the Hilbert space $H\wedge H$, the two clearly coincide (at least up to a phase factor) - simple linear algebra calculation can prove it. But in terms of two $1/2-$spin particles from the Hilbert space $H$, one may think that they are distinct. For example, one may think that one can determine the basis, by an EPR-Bohm experiment. Of course this will not work, since we choose the basis when we choose along which direction of space to measure the spin.

But, is there any known effect in which it matters which basis is used in the singlet state? Is there any kind of "gauge-freedom" associated to the choice of this basis? Are there any theoretical speculations about this?

---

**Update**

Seeing the comments (for which I am grateful), I think I should add more clarifications. I let the original question unchanged, and hope this comment can help clarifying what I mean.

There is no difference between $|\psi\rangle$ and $e^{i\vartheta}|\psi\rangle$. Not in theory, but also not in experiment. Two state vectors which differ by a phase factor are undistinguishable (the state is invariant under the action of the group $U(1)$). But if we can't find the phase, we can find the phase differences. Think at interference, or at the Aharonov-Bohm effect.

Now, the singlet state can be seen as being invariant under $SU(2)$. Did anyone try to do something with this "phase"? If it can't be determined, can we at least determine some "smaller" information, similar to the case of the phase?

Can this suggest an experimental test for the Fock space in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Absolutely not. They ARE the same state, regardless of how you write it.

Comment: @Karsus Ren: Thanks. As one can see from my question, I am aware of this: "As vectors in the Hilbert space $H\wedge H$, the two coincide (at least up to a phase factor)- simple linear algebra calculation can prove it.". But being aware of a theoretical explanation doesn't have to stop us from comparing with experiments.

Comment: @Cristi, I endorse Karsus' answer, of course. There is a more universal source of your confusion. You correctly used the word "represent" in your very question but you don't seem to understand what "represent" means. Representation is a way to talk about something, in your example, about a singlet state. It's a very particular state so it's one thing and can't have different experimental manifestations; it would be a logical oxymoron. If it can be represented differently, the differences are only about the representation - the way how a particular person describes it.

Comment: @CristiStoica: Do you mean to experimentally verify the theoretical prediction that the two states are equivalent in every aspect?

Comment: It is visible from my question that I know that they are the same in the Hilbert space $H\wedge H$. But I am interested if anybody tried to find a way to distinguish them by experiment (that is, to test once more whether the Fock space is the correct representation). Added: I see now your second question Karsus Ren, the answer is yes.

Comment: Karsus Ren and Luboš Motl: I appreciate your effort, which made me realize that maybe I did not phrase the question well enough. Maybe I should edit it, but I will let it as it is, because if I change, it will not be visible to the object of your comments. I hope those interested will understand what I mean if not from question, from the additional comments :)

Comment: Your question is like: Can one distinguish the numbers 1+3 and 2+2 by experiment? It cannot be done as they are just two different ways of referring to the same number 4.

Comment: I also said in the question 'Is there any kind of "gauge-freedom" associated to the choice of this basis?'. For example, two vectors represent the same state, even if they may differ by a phase. While we can't determine the phase, the phase difference can be determined. My question is whether such a "gauge freedom" may appear in this case, but not related to the phase, but to the basis used to represent the singlet state. It seems to me that it will be like an SU(2) symmetry (like the phase has an U(1) symmetry).

Comment: @Arnold Neumaier: Thanks for the comment. Indeed, 1=1, and we can't find the phase by experiment. But we can find the difference of phases. And still 1=1. Why not asking the same about the singlet case? QM is very well tested, like GR is. And still we continue to test them, not without reason. So why not checking if there is something like an SU(2) phase associated to the base in which we represent the singlet state?